# How to get elastic search to return duplicates if at least two words (or 75% of the words) in a title?

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

I need to find duplicates in a database of artwork titles. If there are more than 2 words in the title then I'd like to have at least 2 of the words match (or at least 75% of the words):

*"The Portrait of Dorian Gray"* should **not** match

*"The Portrait of a Lady"* but it should match

*"The Portrait of Dorian G."* as well as

*"The Portrait of Dorian Gray made in 1890"*

I'm using fuzzy matching to catch spelling errors and removing small words like "the", "of", and "a". Currently any title with *Portrait* will get matches by elastic search so I need a way of telling elastic search that at least two of the terms should match.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html is what you are looking for here